# How to exclude directory from -not -newer statement?

Tags: linux, find

Want to find older directories than directory on which I'm using -not -newer statement (it's a part of bigger FIND statement). But can't figure it out how to "protect" this directory from beeing marked as older than itself.

For example

```
find /home/user/data/ -not -newer $variable
```

$variable contains path to this directory, from which I'm trying to find older directories.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure this is what you're asking, but perhaps just exclude the directory explicitly?

`find /home/user/data/ -not -path $variable -not -newer $variable`

This works if you want to exclude a particular location.

```
$ mkdir -p a/b
$ find a -not -newer a
a
a/b
$ find a -not -path a -not -newer a
a/b
```

Comment: I don't wanna sound stupid, but is there such commend as "wholename" ?

Comment: Depends on which `find` you are using. Your command used `-not`, so I assumed `-wholename` was available as well.  `-path` would be more portable.  I'll change it.

Comment: My bad then, but still it's not working, was trying to use -not -path $variable but with same effect.

Comment: Can you give more information, like the exact directory name that is appearing that you don't want and the value of $variable?